# Symfony2 validation - first value is less than second

Tags: php, symfony

I've got entity type of:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="entity")
 */
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $value1;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $value2;
}
```

How to check with validation that `$value1` is less than `$value2`?

Comment: [This](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) should be useful: a validation callback that allows you to compare both values and set violations accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`Expression`**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) constraint in your entity

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="entity")
 */
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @Assert\Expression(
     *     "this.getValue2() < this.getValue1()",
     *     message="Value 1 should be less than value 2"
     *  )
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $value2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, as [the cookbook explains extensively](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html), you'll probably want to add the following to your entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
class Entity
{
    //the values stay the same
     /**
      * @Assert\Callback
      */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if ($this->value1 >= $this->value2)
        {
            $context->buildViolation('Value1 should be less than value2')
                ->atPath('value1')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```